# Ruby execute shell commands in foreground

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, ssh

I'm not asking how to run shell commands in background with ruby but how to make ruby program to stop and launch terminal command.

Background: I made code which simply search all possible Raspberry PI computers which are connected to my main computer with ethernet cable (directly, internet sharing on). The code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

my_ip_cf = `ifconfig eth0`
my_ip_re = /inet addr:([\.\d]*).*/
my_ip = my_ip_cf.match(my_ip_re)[1]

ip_list = eval("`nmap -sP "+my_ip+"/24`")
ip_list_re = /Nmap scan report for ([\.\d]*).*/
ip_match = ip_list.scan(ip_list_re)

puts
if ip_match.length-1 <= 0
    puts "No RPi found!"
else
    puts (ip_match.length-1).to_s+" possible RPis found:"
end
ip_match.length.times do |i|
    puts "\t"+ip_match[i][0] if ip_match[i][0] != my_ip
end
puts
```

So I would make it to execute in same terminal in which the ruby code was running `ssh root@[FOUND_IP]` (Of course ruby code would be stopped at the time of execution of ssh-command) if there are only one possible RPi -IP address.

Comment: Do you expect to have an interactive ssh session? Or do you want to execute one (or a few) commands via ssh and then exit?

Comment: @glennjackman I would like to execute an interactive ssh session.